# How to attain site collection admin rights in a certain subsite

Tags: 2013, permissions, sub-site

I am the site collection admin of the site **`http://server/`**. I am also farm administrator and local admin of the Windows Server account.

However, I do not have access in the site **`http://server/sites/site1`**. How can I make myself admin of site1 ?

EDIT:  I do not have access rights in the central administration.

Comment: If your account is part of Farm Admin group then you should have access to Site1. What error you are getting?

Comment: I get the generic access error page with the message `Sorry, you don't have access to this page`.

Comment: Give yourself full control to the webapplication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`http://server/sites/site1` is a different site collection. Go to the central administration. Select the site collection under the web application and add the account in its list of administrators.

Comment: I am a farm admin, however I do not have access rights in the central administration.

Comment: The site collection admin of this site can give you the admin rights on this site collection

Comment: So the fact that I am the site collection admin of `http://server/` doesn't help?

Comment: Yes both are different.

Answer (score 2):

Two things you can get the access to the site collection:

1. add your account into the Policy of the Web App. this way you will access all site collections in that web app.
2. Or you can go Central admin > Application Management > Change Site collection Administrator...select the web app and then site collection and change it here.

Comment: I am a farm admin, however I do not have access rights in the central administration.

Comment: if you dont have the access to central admin then your account is not farm admin. check under which account SharePoint timer service is running on sharepoint server?

Comment: It is running under an account different from mine. I am pretty sure I am farm admin, I can deploy solutions, etc.

Comment: are you getting the access denied on central admin using your account?

Comment: It keeps asking for username / password even though I provide the correct ones, so I guess, yes.

Comment: try to login on the sahrepoint server with your account and access the central admin from their

Comment: this is what i am doing...

Comment: login with the other farm admin account and browse to the central admin....now make sure your account is part of farm admin.....also try to access the central admin from your pc not server